# ffmpeg: How to repeat an audio "watermark"

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a question concerning FFMpeg. I would like to "inject" a mp3 (beep) file once every e.g. 5 sec into an other mp3 file. Can any of you provide me with some guidance on how to do this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**#1** Process the beep to make it 5 seconds long:

```
ffmpeg -i beep.mp3 -af apad -t 5 beep.wav
```

**#2** Mix with the other audio

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=beep.wav:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[beep];
                                    [0][beep]amix=duration=shortest,volume=2"   out.mp3
```

`loop=0` makes the input loop indefinitely. The asetpts is to make the timestamps of the loop continuous.

Comment: Thx for the help. I'm getting this error however: Output pad "default" with type audio of the filter instance "Parsed_asetpts_1" of asetpts not connected to any destination

Comment: Got it working now. Thx!! 2 small questions now: Can I have and interval between the beeps which is bigger, like every 30 sec? And can I set the path to beep.wav somehow?

Comment: For increasing interval, change `t` value in first command. You can enclose path in quotes: `amovie='/path/to/beep.wav'`

Comment: I thought using a path for the beep.wav would be straight forward but that isn't the case. Somthing like: -filter_complex="amovie=C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\beep.wav:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[beep]" doesn't seem to work

Comment: Apparently it needs to be -filter_complex amovie=c\\:\\\\Users\\\\MyUser\\\\Desktop\\\\beep.wav:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[beep];[0][beep]amix=duration=shortest,volume=2 . Very strange :)

Comment: Use `amovie='C\:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\beep.wav'` Note the quotes and the backslashes.

Comment: Indeed that also works. Thx! A small follow up question what about doing some kind of calculation to have the interval be dynamic, so different when the input file is smaller.

Comment: -af apad -t 5 beep.wav makes remaining part empty but second command trims the empty part making it not useful it plays immediately and not after 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with Gyan's answer causing files to encode as just the first second of audio and nothing else.

For me this slightly adjusted filter works:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=/home/code/watermark.wav:loop=0,volume=2,asetpts=N/SR/TB[bg];[bg][0]amix=duration=shortest" -threads 12 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k outtest.mp3
```