# Audio Watermark Repeat with blank in between

Tags: ffmpeg

I followed answer at [ffmpeg: How to repeat an audio "watermark"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438898/ffmpeg-how-to-repeat-an-audio-watermark)

```
ffmpeg -i beep.mp3 -af apad -t 5 beep.wav

ffmpeg -i main.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=beep.wav:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[beep];
                                    [0][beep]amix=duration=shortest,volume=2"   out.mp3
```

First Command makes beep.wav lengthy with remaining part void audio

but second command trims the empty / void part making beep play immediately and not after 5 seconds

How can i avoid trimming of empty part in second command ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: the same command as was in answer and same as written here. the file that generates is in this link and the beep sound plays continuously once finished we need to pay it after every 5 seconds

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oncz5wkmu1li6vv/output.wav?dl=0

Comment: Share full log for both commands

Comment: In the output.wav, I hear the beep once every 10 seconds.

Comment: hey yes you are right, in browser player, vlc, quicktime its exact after every 10 seconds, but if i play in iTunes in Mac its constantly beeping !!! strange !
if you have mac try it

Comment: My log here
https://jmp.sh/uffJC9t