# ffmpeg: Repeat an audio watermark, except in the first frame

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I've looked at this question: [ffmpeg: How to repeat an audio "watermark"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438898/ffmpeg-how-to-repeat-an-audio-watermark) and I was able to create a watermarked audio file, repeating every x seconds.

However, I need a small variation to the behaviour and I haven't been able to figure it out myself - how can I repeat the watermark every x seconds, AFTER the original audio clip has played for at least x seconds? In other words, I want the watermark to be audible at 10 seconds, 20 seconds and 30 seconds for a 33 second long clip, and currently it's also audible at 0 seconds (i.e. start of the clip).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have followed step 1 in the linked answer. use

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=beep.wav:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,adelay=10s:all=1[beep];
                                [0][beep]amix=duration=shortest,volume=2"   out.mp3
```

The start of the beelp is delayed by 10 seconds. Use a recent git build of ffmpeg, else `all=1` won't be recognized and delay for all channels will have to be set.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. Just read the doc to find out that all=1 delays all channels, and I assume that in this case it's the [beep] stream that we are modifying and it has only one channel that is being delayed 10 seconds. Is that accurate?

Comment: With `all=1`, all channels will be delayed by 10 seconds. Before `all` was added, `10s` would apply to only the first channel.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but in this case, don't we only have a single channel (audio track for beep.wav) which is being processed by this filter? But if I remove the all=1, the watermark is still audible at the start.

Comment: I don't know how many channels your beep file has. `all=1` is added to be safe, in case, there are multiple channels.

Comment: I installed FFMPEG using brew on Mac and when I run the same command, all is not recognized as a valid option for the adelay filter and because of that the command errors out. Have you faced this issue in the past? If so, how can I work around it?

Comment: Does it convert main.mp3 into a mono channel music in out.mp3?

Comment: For some MP3 files, I only get the first second of audio encoded into the output

Comment: Is it posible to add apad to the beep audio? I would like to create a 'space' between beeps but I'm not able to figure out how to get it to work :(

Comment: Add apad to beep.wav and save it as a new WAV. Then use that.