# FFMPEG:Adding beep sound to another audio file in specific time portions

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I've a scenario in which I need to modify certain portions of audio file.Currently,I'm able to add silence to the audio file at specific portions through FFMPEG audio filter -af.But is there something that can replace particular portions of audio with beep sound and the duration of the file should be same after the process?

Eg: Input.wav,I want to add beep of 10s-15s(i.e.,5 seconds) to the file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ffmpeg: How to repeat an audio "watermark"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438898/ffmpeg-how-to-repeat-an-audio-watermark)

Answer (score 3):

Replace audio with beep from 10 to 15 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -filter_complex "[0]volume=0:enable='between(t,10,15)'[main];sine=d=5:f=800,adelay=10s,pan=stereo|FL=c0|FR=c0[beep];[main][beep]amix=inputs=2" output.wav
```

- [sine](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sine) - makes beep sound
- [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) - adds a delay to position the beep
- [pan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) - one of many methods to convert the beep from mono to stereo
- [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) - mixes the beep into the main audio

If the beep occurs almost immediately at 10 milliseconds instead of at 10 seconds then your `ffmpeg` is old and you have to declare milliseconds instead of seconds: `adelay=10000`.

Comment: Hi @llogan, How can I possibly change it to add beeps to different sections with varying durations? Created a new question in case you can have a look :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70076710/beeping-out-portions-of-an-audio-file-using-ffmpeg

Comment: warning: the last filter amix may cause the original audio volume down! think that you delay the sine audio source for 10s. that means the previous 10s' content is muted. then you mix original audio and muted audio together. but the amix algorithm use Weighted Average, and default weight is 1:1(whose total weight is 2)，if your original audio level is 100, the previous 10's sine audio level is 0.  the final level is 100* 1 /(1+1) = 50, 0* 1/(1+1) =0, 50+0=50. see? the final audio level is only 50!