# Beeping out portions of an audio file using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to beep out sections of an audio file (say 10-15 and 20-30). However only the first portion(10-20) gets beeped, whilst the next portion gets muted.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]volume=0:enable='between(t,10,15)+between(t,20,30)'[main];sine=d=5:f=800,adelay=10s,pan=stereo|FL=c0|FR=c0[beep];[main][beep]amix=inputs=2" output.wav
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59937864/13639008) as my reference, but not able to make much progress.

Edit : Well, `sine=d=5` clearly mentions the duration as 5 (my bad). Seems like this command can be used to add beeping to only one specific portion, how can I possibly change it to add beeps to different sections with varying durations.

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "volume=enable='between(t,5,10)':volume=0[main];sine=d=5:f=800,adelay=5s,pan=stereo|FL=c0|FR=c0[beep];[main][beep]amix=inputs=2,
volume=enable='between(t,15,20)':volume=0[main];sine=d=5:f=800,adelay=15s,pan=stereo|FL=c0|FR=c0[beep];[main][beep]amix=inputs=2, volume=enable='between(t,40,50)':volume=0[main];sine=d=10:f=800,adelay=40s,pan=stereo|FL=c0|FR=c0[beep];[main][beep]amix=inputs=2" output.wav
```

The above code beeps `5-10`, `15-20` and `40-50`

This seems to work. Separating the different beeping settings with a ,(comma) and making changes at all 3 places: `between`, `sine=d=x` where x seems to be the duration and `adelay=ys` where y is the delay, meaning when the beeping starts. So between would be `(t, y, y+x)`.

References : [Mute specified sections of an audio file using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62657688/10077354) and [FFMPEG:Adding beep sound to another audio file in specific time portions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59937864/10077354)

Would love to know a more easier/convenient way of doing this. So I'm not marking this as an answer.